lightgbm classifier: predictions are all 1
I have a lightGBM classifier model that I want to train on un_balanced data. In the training set there are 32500 1's and 2898 0's . The no of features are 30 and 17 of them are categorical data. This is how I am training the data . All the predictions are becoming 1's .
params_dict = dict(
        objective="binary",
        early_stopping_round=30,
        num_threads=-1,
        learning_rate=0.01,
        verbosity=1,
        is_unbalance=True,
        max_depth=15,
        num_leaves=30,
        num_iterations=500,
        min_child_samples=1000,
    )
model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(**params_dict)
model.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train, eval_set =[(X_valid, y_valid)] )



This is common when you deal with unbalanced data. Here I give you some possible solutions. First you can stratify the train and test split. Then you can pass another scorer for the model, for example: recall or f1. You also can use a model where you can pass the class_weight parameter, for example Logistic Regression or Random Forest. Another option is to generate sinthetic data with SMOTE, this will balance your data.
I give you some examples:
Train and test split with stratification:
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, df['TARGET'],test_size=0.15,random_state=0,stratify=df['TARGET'])

Class weight, so maybe you get better results with another model:
class_weight='balanced'

Or you can try different weights:
[{0: w} for w in [1, 2, 10]] + ['balanced']

If you are sure you want to use LGBMClassifier, i thin SMOTE is your better option, you can read here an example: smote-oversampling_for-imbalanced-classification
You have to be careful with the sinthetic data and validate over your real data.
Hope it helps.

This seems like the right answer to me, but just thought I'd add some clarification of why you're getting this result. The model is training to get the highest accuracy possible. If your target variable had 99 labels of 1 and one label of 0, it would achieve 99% accuracy by just classifying everything as a 1 (the 99 ones are correct, the single 0 is incorrect. 99/100 correct). This is why you need to remedy with one of these solutions mentioned here.

Have a look at some critics for SMOTE:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/why-smote-is-not-used-in-prize-winning-kaggle-solutions
https://juandelacalle.medium.com/i-declare-myself-the-1-enemy-of-over-undersampling-smote-and-adasyn-heres-why-how-i-5889b5073419
It distorts the nature of your dataset in the way that you don't want
